# Is there any app for translating Localizable.strings file?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, localization

I mean, if I have some Localizable.strings file with some text:

```
/* Cancel string */
"Cancel" = "Cancel";
```

That app will translate it to spanish (ex.):

```
/* Cancel string */
"Cancel" = "Cancelar";
```

For android there is already such service:
http://translate.google.com/toolkit

Comment: Using machine translation is a really bad idea for localization. Your app will very possibly be unusable.

Comment: I'd go further and say it's a crime to localize an app using machine translation. Don't do it! As an example, in my company (where they have foolishly been doing machine translation for some products) we found that the Spanish translation for "Back" (a button) is the word for someone's back. It's utterly ridiculous.

Comment: What the problem??? :))) I just asked if there is such a tool...

Comment: There is no like manual translation, but in case you want something fast and no impact for your users (for development purposes for example) I used google translator toolkit

Comment: There exists the new tool attranslate that does exactly what you are asking for: https://github.com/fkirc/attranslate

Answer (score 4):

Who is stopping you using Googles Translator Toolkit?
You can upload:

```
> AdWords Editor Archive (.aea)
> Android Resource (.xml) 
> Application Resource Bundle (.arb) 
> Chrome Extension (.json) 
> GNU gettext (.po) 
> HTML (.html) 
> Microsoft Word (.doc) 
> OpenDocument Text (.odt) 
> Plain Text (.txt) 
> Rich Text (.rtf) 
> SubRip (.srt) 
> SubViewer (.sub)
```

You have to copy paste your localized strings in one of file type above translate it and copy paste it back. You can write an automator script that does this for you.

Comment: I can write many things, and app like that too. But I have asked if there is such an app already? And if I just copy paste strings file to any format, google service translates all of the contents include comments and id's...

Comment: Google Translate Toolkit also handles Localizable.strings format

Comment: Seems to be broke now.

Comment: Google Translate Toolkit is gone now.

Comment: Google is stopping me. "As of December 4, 2019, Google Translator Toolkit has shut down."

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a translation tool that translates  .txt file , .string files and .xml files into multiple languages.
Install: `$pip install mkTranslation`

Usage:

```
$translate -p  ./ios.strings  -d 'en'  # translation file
$translate -p ./android.xml -d 'ja'  # translation file
$translate  'mkTranslate supports multilingual translations' -d 'pt'   # translation text
```

**demo:**

```
from  
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <!-- tab -->
    <string name="network_error">网络不可用，点击屏幕重试</string>
    <string name="scan_qr_code_warn">将二维码放入框内，即可自动扫描</string>
    <string name="album_text">相册</string>
</resources>
to  
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <!-- tab -->
    <string name="network_error">Network is not available, click screen to try again</string>
    <string name="scan_qr_code_warn">Put the QR code into the box and you can scan it automatically.</string>
    <string name="album_text">Album</string>
</resources>
```

The default translation is google translation, you can specify other translation channels

**Code:https://github.com/mythkiven/mkTranslate**

Answer (score 1):

I've used Google Translate Toolkit with it's handling for Localizable.strings. It worked pretty well.

There is this product that I've just seen advertised on Stack Overflow. Obviously as a result of my searches! It promises to relieve a lot of the manual burden. I haven't used it yet so can't comment.

It's [TraductoPro](http://www.traductoapp.com)

Comment: The app is dead now

Answer (score 0):

My job is to localize Localizable.strings files and I can tell you that there are plenty of options available. The most bare-bones one if you are doing it yourself is to use TextWrangler on the Mac. It color codes the file so it is easy to translate the right-side into whichever language you need. I highly recommend it if doing by hand. But you want it done automatically.

For that, it's best to wrap it up in a tool that separates the formatting code from the actual text. **We use [Crowdin.com](https://crowdin.com)** to do this. It has a lot of advantages as far as parsing localization formats (also Android .strings, gettext .pot, etc.). You can also crowdsource the translation for free or use existing translation memories, which do not result in a great product, but are certainly better than Google Translate. You can also hire a real [app localization service](http://www.ibabbleon.com/app_localization.html) company to do it. :)

Answer (score -2):

this may help you automatically generate the corresponding language localizable.strings file and also translate it by using googletranslate
https://github.com/duycao2506/ios_localizable_translator.